# Deploy a Flask app with gunicorn (exploreflask tuto)

Tags: python, flask, deployment, gunicorn

To understand how to deploy a Flask app, I read some tutos and found the one of [exploreflask](http://exploreflask.com) quite good.

I used the [blueprints-functional structure](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html)  to build my test-app, BUT at the end, at the [deployment part](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/deployment.html) with an application runner like gunicorn, the tuto uses a example with one unique file, quite different of the rest

```
arandomfoldername/
    config.py
    requirements.txt
    run.py
    instance/
      config.py
    myappname/
        __init__.py
        static/
        templates/
            home/
            control/
        views/
            __init__.py
            home.py
            control.py
        models.py
```

And

```
# myappname/__init__.py
from flask import Flask
from .views.home import bluehome 
from .views.control import bluecontrol 

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.register_blueprint(bluehome)
app.register_blueprint(bluecontrol)
```

So I tried `gunicorn myappname:app` but I got a `No module named myappname`, the `app` variable is in the `__init_.py` in the `myappname` package (as the tuto shows in the blueprints part)

I used this [flask tuto](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/deploy/) to build the wheel file

1. How to manage and fix this ?
2. How the parameters given in the top-file `config.py` are supposed to utile as they are not used in the wheel file ?

Comment: Does it work if you put the app module in quotes? E.g. `gunicorn 'myappname:app'`? Also, since you're starting from scratch, I'd recommend giving serious thought to adopting the [App Factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appfactories/) pattern now. It lets you avoid circular dependencies which you'll eventually run into with Flask projects, especially those using Blueprints. In that case, your `gunicorn` would look like this: `gunicorn 'myappname:create_app()'`

Comment: @NickK9 the factory method should be in the init.py ? Not found this info in the tuto

Comment: That's right. Then you put something like this in your run.py: `from myappname import create_app; app = create_app()`. Here's [another tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure) which discusses migrating to using the App Factory pattern.

Comment: @NickK9 I think I get it, I don't need a wheel install file, as some tutos tell, I just need the top-folder of the project and then just run gunicorn^^

Comment: Let me know if my suggestion works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In somes tutos, like [`flask.pocoo`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/deploy/) it says to build a wheel file and install it, but gunicorn doesn't use this way.

- use the `Factory` pattern
- use a file named for ex `wsgi.py` to import the `app` from the factory

---

Then copy the whole folder in the production venv:

```
arandomfoldername/
    config.py
    requirements.txt
    run.py
    instance/
      config.py
    myappname/
        __init__.py
        wsgi.py
        static/
        templates/
            home/
            control/
        views/
            __init__.py
            home.py
            control.py
        models.py
```

And then

```
cd arandomfoldername
gunicorn myappname.wsgi:app
```